# Does India finance terrorists in Pakistan?

Tags: india, pakistan

[On February 2014](http://www.newsnation.in/article/146274-who-is-indias-nsa-ajit-doval-and-what-is-doval-doctrine.html), India's 5th national security advisor [Ajit Doval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajit_Doval) was seen [giving away speech](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v4RaCJrT51w) in Sastra University saying that:

> - ... India needs to go into the 'offensive-defensive' mode when dealing with a rogue state like Pakistan. India should tackle the problem where it originated ...
> - ... You may do one Mumbai; you may lose Balochistan ...
> - ... Either Pakistan give up terrorism against India as a state policy or India would let it bleed with the Taliban ...

In wake of the capture of alleged Indian spy, [Kulbhushan Jadav](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kulbhushan_Jadhav), India had been accused of supporting and harboring terrorists.

- [What the Kulbhushan Jadhav Saga Reveals About India and Pakistan’s Balochistan Problems](https://thediplomat.com/2018/01/what-the-kulbhushan-jadhav-saga-reveals-about-india-and-pakistans-balochistan-problems/)

Neighboring old-time foe Pakistan has long accused India of using terrorism as an instrument to fuel unrest in Pakistan's restive province of Balochistan.

- [India Said To Be Sponsoring Terrorism In Pakistan: Fact Check](https://www.valuewalk.com/2017/09/india-terrorism-pakistan/)
- [India financing terrorist groups in Pakistan, says FO](https://tribune.com.pk/story/1523524/us-cant-make-pakistan-scapegoat-failures-afghanistan-fo/)
- [RAW-TTP nexus sponsoring terror in Pakistan: FO](https://nation.com.pk/29-Sep-2017/raw-ttp-nexus-sponsoring-terror-in-pakistan-fo)

India obviously denies all the accusations.

So my question is that is there any evidence to prove that India is instigating terrorism in Pakistan?

Comment: "Definite evidence" in these situations is not an absolute term. eg. When Kasab was caught red-handed in Mumbai attacks, Pakistan initially refused to agree that he was theirs.

Comment: You didn't get the point I made. Anyway here's the link. https://www.reuters.com/article/idINIndia-47977620100425

Answer (score 3):

Hindustan Times article *[Afghanistan, Pakistan and the F-16: Mattis has to hardsell these issues on his visit to India](https://www.hindustantimes.com/analysis/afghanistan-pakistan-and-the-f-16-mattis-has-to-hardsell-these-issues-on-his-visit-to-india/story-qvL9NS6wgl17sy756hE2WN.html)* published in September 2017 say that:

> On the other issue, as a former head of the US Central Command Mattis
>   appreciates Pakistan’s indispensability as base for military
>   operations to bring the Taliban in Afghanistan to their knees. But
>   Islamabad has insisted that India’s role in Afghanistan be restricted
>   and complained about the Indian support for the Tehrik-e-Taliban
>   Pakistan (TTP) accused by Islamabad of terrorism in Pakistan. **The
>   RAW-TTP link was publicly revealed in April this year by its former
>   commander, Ehsanullah Ehsan.**
>
> Mattis’ request that India moderate its support for TTP will put Delhi
>   in a fix because **TTP is useful as an Indian counterpart of the Hizbul
>   Mujahideen, Lashkar-e-Toiba, and Jaish-e-Mohammad** deployed by the
>   Pakistan Inter-Services Intelligence (ISI) in Jammu & Kashmir.
>   Severing relations with TTP will mean India surrendering an active
>   card in Pakistan and a role in Afghanistan as TTP additionally
>   provides access to certain Afghan Taliban factions.

This means Indian government has a definite collaboration with some terrorists in Pakistan notably **[TTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tehrik-i-Taliban_Pakistan)**.

Comment: "some terrorists in Afghanistan" — But the question is about terrorists in Pakistan.

Comment: @jwodder Tehrik-i-Taliban Pakistan = TTP. They operate on both Pakistan and Afghanistan.